# Display square root at input text?

Tags: javascript, css, html, button, sqrt

How to display square root in the input text box from a calci buttons with overline. For example if we want to display a string 80(√2345)68 in which square root with overline at 2345(ignore braces.). Please help !!

Comment: I think you can't have a full square root draw in a input field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [google charts infographic](https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/docs/formulas).

For example :

```
<img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=\sqrt(1234)%2Ba^2">
```

would show up as [image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to use an engine to render the math related text/formulas. A popular one is [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/), check their [Documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/start.html).

Comment: Thanks! I will try.

Answer (score 0):

MathJax Extension: forminput [mathjax-ext-contrib](https://github.com/leathrum/mathjax-ext-contrib/tree/master/forminput) having  [sample](http://leathrum.github.io/mathjax-ext-contrib/forminput/sample.html)

Below is code from above sample

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Add \Input to MathJax</title>
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  extensions: ["http://cs.jsu.edu/mathjax-ext/github/forminput/forminput.js"],
  styles: {
    ".MathJax_Input": { "margin": "0 2px" },
    ".red_background": { "background-color": "#F88" }
  }
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>

</head>
<body>

<p>
Here is an equation with form elements: 
\(\FormInput{a}x+\FormInput[][red_background]{b}\).
</p>

<p>
Here is another:
\[
\int_{\FormInput[][][2]{lowlim}}^{\FormInput{highlim}} x^3\,dx = 
\left.\frac{x^{\FormInput[2]{n}}}{\FormInput{m}}\right]_2^7
\]
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

**Edit**

Matching expression which is asked in question

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Add \Input to MathJax</title>
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  extensions: ["http://cs.jsu.edu/mathjax-ext/github/forminput/forminput.js"],
  styles: {
    ".MathJax_Input": { "margin": "0 2px" },
    ".red_background": { "background-color": "#F88" }
  }
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>

</head>
<body>


<p>
  
 <b>square root in the input text box with overline</b> for 80(√2345)68
\[
\ 80\left(\sqrt{\FormInput[][][]{sqrt}}\right)68
\]

</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @user7515042  updated answer according to your question. For more reference [check here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Thanks Deep!! ... Actually i am making a calculator to enter the values of square roots and powers. So when we hit the buttons then the corresponding values will be reflected onto the input text box and facing problems for square root to display its overline property. It will be greatfull if u provide some more help.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.